# amcharts how to add a line between 2 graphs

Tags: amcharts

I am working on creating a bar chart using amcharts I have it correctly displaying the information, but need a line break between two graphs.

I am pulling data for version of code running in two different modes, and have one mode in one graph and the other in another.

Example: graph has data for modea and the RC and GA releases for that code line. graph two has data for modeb and the RC and GA releases for that code line. The versions are the same only the mode is different.

They display in the correct order, I just cannot get a line break between the 2 to show a separation.

Example Code:

```
var chart;
 var chartData = [{
    os: "2.1",
    GAc: 2,
    RCc: 1
},{
    os: "2.2",
    GAc: 6,
    RCc: 1
 },{
    os: "2.1",
    GAb: 5,
    RCb: 1
},{
    os: "2.2",
    GAb: 2,
    RCb: 9
}];

AmCharts.ready(function () {
    chart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();
    chart.dataProvider = chartData;
    chart.categoryField = "os";
    chart.plotAreaBorderAlpha = 0.2;
    chart.numberFormatter = {
            precision : 0
        };
    var categoryAxis = chart.categoryAxis;
        categoryAxis.gridAlpha = 0.1;
        categoryAxis.axisAlpha = 0
        categoryAxis.gridPosition = "start";
        categoryAxis.autoWrap = true;
        categoryAxis.labelRotation = 90;
    var valueAxis = new AmCharts.ValueAxis();
        valueAxis.stackType = "regular";
        valueAxis.gridAlpha = 0.1;
        valueAxis.axisAlpha = 0;
        chart.addValueAxis(valueAxis);

    var graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
        graph.title = "Mode-Charlie";
        graph.valueField = "GAc";
        graph.type = "column";
        graph.lineAlpha = 0;
        graph.fillAlphas = 1;
        graph.lineColor = "orange";
        chart.addGraph(graph);
    var graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
        graph.title = "Mode-Charlie";
        graph.valueField = "RCc";
        graph.type = "column";
        graph.lineAlpha = 0;
        graph.fillAlphas = 1;
        graph.lineColor = "blue";
        chart.addGraph(graph);

    var graph2 = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
        graph2.title = "Mode-Beta";
        graph2.valueField = "GAb";
        graph2.type = "column";
        graph2.lineAlpha = 0;
        graph2.fillAlphas = 1;
        graph2.lineColor = "orange";
        chart.addGraph(graph2);
    var graph2 = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
        graph2.title = "Mode-Beta";
        graph2.valueField = "RCb";
        graph2.type = "column";
        graph2.lineAlpha = 0;
        graph2.fillAlphas = 1;
        graph2.lineColor = "blue";
        chart.addGraph(graph2);

        chart.write("chartdiv");
  });
```

Comment: Do you mean you want some kind of vertical line between the two groups of stacks to be drawn?

Comment: You also had a couple of typos in your code (cateforyField instead of categoryField, as well as quote instead of comma). I have edited them as those do not seem to be related to the question. Just letting you know the code is updated.

Comment: Thanks for the correction on those two misses. Yes I would like a line or some kind of break. What i have been trying is to get them to group so that all of them that are mode1 would show up with the OS grouped and labeled as mode1 then mode2 would be grouped as well. I just cannot seem to find a way to do that.

Comment: Thanks. Just so we're on the same page, do you need something like this? (I'll post an answer explaining everything if it is correct) http://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/4d457dbe87c74ec27804a8b617f77177

Comment: That is pretty close, what I am looking for is to group the modes it would have Mode-Charlie and 2.1 and 2.2  then have Mode-Beta and 2.1 and 2.2 listed there.